# Drawing arrows between images macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm working on a SwiftUI view that should show images loaded from disk with arrows between them. The structure of my view is basically this:

```
ScrollView
- HStack
-- ForEach
--- GeometryReader
---- Image
```

My thought process is that I can just use the GeometryReader to find the current position of each image in the ScrollView and then draw a line between two Images using a Path. Am I at least on the right track? I've also noticed using GeometryReader kills performance in a major way and do not think this is the correct way to get the position of each Image unless I'm just using it incorrectly.

Here's the code that I have so far:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ScreenshotView: View {
    let screenshots = getScreenshots()
    

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(screenshots, id: \.self) { screenshot in
                    GeometryReader { geo in
                        // have to use NSImage to load from disk
                        if let nsImage = NSImage(
                            contentsOf: screenshot.path) {
                            Button(action: {
                                print("Trying to open: ", screenshot.path)
                                NSWorkspace.shared.open(screenshot.path)
                            }) {
                                Image(nsImage: nsImage)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .frame(width: 50, height: 100)
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                    .padding()
                                    .coordinateSpace(name: "image")
                            }
                            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                            .help("\(geo.frame(in: .global).midX)")
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 100)
                    .padding()
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: could you specify "arrow between them"? what kind of arrows?  from where to where should the arrows go? only horizontal or across the view?

Comment: Yeah, just horizontally between the two images. From the right side of the left image to the left side of the right image. (I'll later be using a VStack so in that case vertically between the two images). Doesn't necessarily need to be an arrow like --->, it could just be a line or ---o something like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `GeometryReader`. Just put the arrow between the images in the `HStack`. If you don't want spacing, adjust it in the `HStack`, e.g. `spacing: 0`.

The `Shape` is a single view in itself, which does not need absolute position points, but sizes itself in regards to the parent view, or like in this example in the size given by `.frame`.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<10) { _ in
                    Rectangle().fill(.gray)
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    ArrowShape()
                        .stroke(lineWidth: 2)
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 20)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ArrowShape: Shape{
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        
        let delta = rect.height / 2  // height of arrow tip legs
        
        return Path{ path in
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.midY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY))
            
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - delta, y: rect.midY - delta))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - delta, y: rect.midY + delta))
        }
    }
}
```